# Cassandra Connection Refuse

Tags: cassandra

I have a cluster's casssandra but I can't login by JMX on 7199. I know that you must have enabled remove access. Where to do it? When you connect through JConsole refuses to connect. Thank you for all the help

Comment: You will need to be more specific with your question.  Please elaborate and I'll do my best to help you!  Please provide C* version, protocol you're attempt to connect with, client, etc.

Comment: You may wish to edit this question for clarity - I get the gist of your problem, but it is poorly worded. Answered below.

Comment: I do not want anything to himself I reach what is wrong

Comment: Please don't vandalise your question, that is not fair to those that answered it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cassandra JMX only listens to localhost for security reasons. If you wish to open up remote connections, read https://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/JmxSecurity for details on how to do this properly. The configurations for setting up JMX are in `conf/cassandra-env.sh`.

Answer (score -1):

To connect to cassanra remotely you need to update your **cassandra.yaml** file present under the **/conf/cassandra.yaml** directory.

Please refer to the [link](http://techpost360.blogspot.in/2015/07/connect-cassandra-remotely.html)

**seeds: "127.0.0.1"**

**to**

**seeds: "YOUR_LOCAL_MACHINE_IP"**   (*keep the doubles quotes)

**listen_address: localhost**

**to**

**listen_address: YOUR_LOCAL_MACHINE_IP**

**rpc_address: localhost**

**to**

**rpc_address: YOUR_LOCAL_MACHINE_IP**